# Editor to draw program logic and focus on big picture?

Tags: windows, editor

This question has probably been asked before, but I don't know what keywords to use to find previous answers.

When writing code, I tend to get lost in details, and would like some editor that I can use to be able to move from the little picture (actual code) to the big picture (big blocks of logic).

Ideally, it should integrate with the Delphi IDE (2007 or 2009), but it's OK if it's a stand-alone Windows application.

Does someone know of such a tool?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers on Visio, SmartDraw, and Argo UML.

Actually, I think it'd be pretty useful to be able to select a bunch of code, set some label to it, and have an editor like SmartDraw to be able to draw the different blocks with some arrows between them to see how the application flows.

Comment: Part of the problem is that every programmer uses different strategies for maintaining large amounts of code.  I try to develop my code in such a way that when I need to find something, I can search for it, since I essentially memorize key identifiers.  Visual Studio's Find feature does the rest.  As for visualizing, I find its faster to write modular, well-named code, organized into folders and namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use Microsoft Visio - it works for organizational charts, as well as flowcharts for complex algorithms.

Any Visio alternative like OpenOffice Draw should work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing skeleton frameworks of your classes, so that you define what sort of accessors and methods they contain, and how they relate to other classes in your application. This is more of an architectural process than writing the implementation of each method, which you can proceed to do afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [SmartDraw](http://www.smartdraw.com/) for a long time with no complaints - it's one of the best IMO.

Answer (score 0):

[Argo UML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) works well.